# Anchor tag link is not navigating to desired page in Microsoft Teams Desktop app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to create a simple tab in Microsoft Teams Desktop app, I have included the iframe in Microsoft Teams tab configuration. 
In the PageOne.jsp, I have provided a anchor link to PageTwo.jsp (PageOne.jsp is iframed in Microsoft teams Tab), When I click the anchor link it is not navigating to PageTwo.jsp, it is showing blank page.

Do I need to enable any permissions in manifest.json file while sideloading the app in MSteams.?

Or else is this an issue in Teams Desktop App. ?

In Microsoft Teams Web App, the pages are navigating as expected with anchor tags.

Comment: Is PageTwo.jsp in the same domain as PageOne.jsp? If no, is it listed in the validDomains array?

Also, do you see any warning or error messages in the browser DevTools console when running it in the browser?

Comment: Hi @BillBliss-MSFT , the PageTwo.jsp is hosted in same domain (Both Pageaone.jsp and PageTwo.jsp) running in same instance of the server and that domain name is included in the Valid domain array in Manifest.json file.

Comment: This issue is happening only in Teams Desktop app, with Teams Web application there is no issue. There is no error or warning messages showing while clicking hyperlink (anchor tags).